# Apache отказывается работать от имени пользователя

Tags: php, apache, веб-сервер

Как настроить чтобы Apache работал от имени пользователя mypc а не от www-data ? 
Прочитал много форумов и везде пишут сделать так.

1 - Редактировать файл /etc/apache2/envvars

```
поменять это
```

export APACHE_RUN_USER=`www-data` 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=`www-data`

```
на это
```

export APACHE_RUN_USER=`mypc` 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=`mypc`

Все никак не могут понять, все пишут что у них все заработало и все отлично.
А вот у меня Apache после этого просто отказывается запускаться, как сменю настройки на старые все работает.
Что тут не так ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема Решена, ниже напишу по порядку может понадобится кому. 
**ОС Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 

Apache2 + PHP7.0-fpm**

для начала желательно сделать backup /etc/php и /etc/apache2 
(Я не делал,люблю рисковать)

1 - для начала открываем temrinal и добавляем пользователя в свою группу , тк если имя пользователя mypc то:

```
adduser mypc mypc
```

2 - заходим в /etc/apache2/ пишем в терминале gedit envvars

находим строчки :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data 
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

cмело меняем их на

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=mypc
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=mypc
```

3 - `systemctl restart apache2`

Вот что выдаст apache

```
Job for apache2.service failed ......
```

4 - открываем терминал и вводим

```
journalctl | tail
```

**AH00526: Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf**

**/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi: can't create dynamic directory**

5 - Открываем Nautilus из под root , даем права и делаем пользователя mypc владельцем `/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi`

6 - `systemctl restart apache2` 
**[ok] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.service.** 
**apache2.service - active (running)**

```
127.0.0.1/info.php
```

выдаст

```
Internal Server Error = PHP не хочет работать.
```

8 - Открываем Terminal и вводим

```
grep -r www-data /etc/php/7.0/

/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:user = www-data
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:group = www-data
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:listen.owner = www-data
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:listen.group = www-data
```

9 - открываем поочереди все эти файлы через gedit и меняем www-data на mypc

10 - Открываем Nautilus из под root и даем права mypc на папку `/etc/php/`

11 - Открываем Nautilus из под root и даем права mypc на папку `/etc/apache2/` 
Запускаем 127.0.0.1/info.php и радуемся жизни. 
Больше не придется для каждой папки раздавать права доступа.

Подобное рекомендуется практиковать на локальном хостинге, 
 для всех остальных случаев есть libapache2_mpm_itk , мне было лень его настраивать,
 и толковой информации не нашел в инете, поэтому сделал так как описано выше.